# R and image processing

Tags: r, image-processing

I've started R langage for school recently. We are asked to do some image processing, and generally the modifications are pixels by pixels (for example for HSI color space : http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HSL_and_HSV)

But with R we can't simply do this using two nested for loops, because the langage is too slow.

What is the best way to process an image using R, to apply a modification pixel by pixel?

Comment: Use vectorization rather than nested loops. And Ihaka's papers are relevant:https://www.stat.auckland.ac.nz/~ihaka/?Papers_and_Talks

Comment: I've never looked into it much but the package `EBImage` may be helpful.

Comment: I suggest adding some example data, and a proposed operation or outcome. That will turn this into a programming question, and elicit some practical answers.

Answer (score 0):

This depends heavily on the modifications you're using. R is capable of performant matrix operations, and if you're able to describe the modifications you're using in terms of these operations, it's fine.

You may want to read about the apply-family of functions, which are commonly used in place of loops. They execute faster than for loops.